# Why can taskAffinity and allowEmbedded be used in the WatchFaceService <service> tag?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm looking at the [training page](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/service.html) for creating an Android Wear Watchface and I noticed this snippet

```
<service
    android:name=".AnalogWatchFaceService"
    android:label="@string/analog_name"
    android:allowEmbedded="true"
    android:taskAffinity=""
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
```

Now, what's peculiar to me are the `android:allowEmbedded` and `android:taskAffinity` properties. These are both properties that can be used in activities, per the [docs page for `<activity>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html). However, they don't seem to be defined for services, per the [docs page for `<service>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html). Can someone explain to me why these properties can be used in the service tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two attributes are indeed not needed and shouldn't be there; I will open an internal ticket to update the documentation; thanks for bringing that to our attention.

Comment: Really? Awesome. Thanks so much. I'll award the bounty as soon as I can.